# angular2 loadChildren is not getting observable subscribe data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, observable

The same code works perfectly if I import the module in main module which bootstraps but does not work if it's defined in a router and loaded using loadChildren

```
  //router mapping
  {
    path: 'overview',
    loadChildren: 'ein-overview#OverviewModule'
  }


  //defining observable and updating its value
  private _customerDetail = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  customerDetail$         = this._customerDetail.asObservable();

  processCustomerDetail(n : any) {
    this._customerDetail.next(n);
  }
```

My component which loaded using loadChildren not getting the update when there is any update from the obserbable.

```
this.subscription = this._customerOverviewService.customerDetail$.subscribe(
        (customer : number) => this.customer = customer
);

//template 
<p>{{customer.messages}}</p>
<p>{{customer.contactPhone}}</p>
<p>{{customer.primaryPhone}}</p>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you put your observable in a service, yes? So where do you provide it then? It should be working just fine if it's in your AppModule (or CoreModule) so that all components will get the same instance of the service.. otherwise you might end up with several instances. Have a look at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#04-11

Comment: Can you add code for both App and Child Modules,

Comment: @benny_boe, removing the service from chield module provides list solved the problem. actually the chield was creating another service and binding to it and parent module service object was different